# Hard drive ignores hdparm settings

Tags: hard-disk, power-management, hdparm

An external hard disk sold as “INTENSO USB 3.0 4TB M/CNTR DSKTP HDD PK1” with the model number given by `hdparm -I` as `ST4000DM000-1F2168` (so it's a Seagate Technology drive in the casing) just flat out *ignores* my power saving options set by `hdparm`.

```
root@igloo: hdparm -S 244 /dev/sdb        

/dev/sdb:
 setting standby to 244 (2 hours)
```

=> it still keeps spinning down after just 10 minutes. I absolutely verified that `/dev/sdb` is the right disk.

A clean solution to make the disk follow the power saving option is much preferred. If this is not possible what would be the best workaround?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: before I set anything with hdparm, it also spins down after ten minutes

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Is it some hard-coded spin-down time?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I misread your intention.

Comment: check out [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248091/119298) to use `hdparm -B 254` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the option `hdparm -Z` to "*disable the automatic power-saving function of certain Seagate drives (ST3xxx models?), to prevent them from idling/spinning-down at inconvenient times.*"

Although yours is a Seagate ST4xxx model it may work for you too.

There's also `hdparm -B 254` that will "*Get/set Advanced Power Management feature, if the drive supports it.*" (Taken from [What could be causing my hard drive to spin down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248091/100397), which suggests that this setting will then allow the `hdparm -S` feature to work as expected.)

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, the `-Z` gives me an error message.

Comment: ok, `hdparm -B 254` seems to work. Does it have to be set again at every system boot?

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats I would imagine so. On my Debian (wheezy) box there are a couple of places to put these configuration statements, though: `/etc/default/hdparm` and `/etc/hdparm.conf`. If you're on a different distro I assume there'll be something similar.